# Both SVM and Clustering ? Confusion

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, classification, svm

I am reading a paper about language classification. The paper is pretty much "easy" to understand except one part. They use both clustering and svm classification. I have read the paper many times but I cant exactly understand when and why they do the svm classification.

They cluster the feature space, fair enough. But what is the purpose of svm? Is the training of the system achieved by the multi class svm?

This is how I understand it; Firstly, they use svm to train the system with labeled images, second they extract the features and they cluster the features within the class for every image.

This might sound very naïve to you, but I am new into this area and trying really hard to understand this! Thanks a lot, in advance!

[This is](http://lampsrv02.umiacs.umd.edu/pubs/Papers/Zhu_ICFHR2008/Zhu_ICFHR2008.pdf) the paper I am talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) They extracted the low-level shape features (triple adjacent contour segments (TAS)) from the image with the help of image processing algorithms such as edge/contour detection,  (ii) they defined feature dissimilarity, (iii) they defined a kernel function, and used the function as a standard for the clustering, (iv) they used SVM to learn which label(language) corresponds to a given clustering.

The unsupervised clustering method mainly helps different languages be classified into different groups based on the shape feature, yet given the fact that we already know several handwritings represent a same language, it is still unknown which language they are. As a result, a supervised learning is needed.